Using espnow and wifi station simultaneously on eps32c6
I'm getting a lot of help from stackoverflow, but this is my first time asking a question. My problem is this: Successfully transmitted data between two esp32c6 development boards using espnow communication. However, if you change one of the two to a wifi station and try to connect to the external Internet, espnow communication fails. In any case, it runs without failure when run independently, but the moment you connect espnow communication and the wifi station, espnow communication fails. Below is an example code. All were created by slightly modifying the example provided by esp-idf.
#include <string.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/event_groups.h"
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_wifi.h"
#include "esp_event.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "nvs_flash.h"

#include "lwip/err.h"
#include "lwip/sys.h"
#include "esp_now.h"
#include "esp_mac.h"


#define EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID      "KT_GiGA_Mesh_E2FB"
#define EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS      "8zx46he056"
#define EXAMPLE_ESP_MAXIMUM_RETRY  CONFIG_ESP_MAXIMUM_RETRY

#if CONFIG_ESP_WPA3_SAE_PWE_HUNT_AND_PECK
#define ESP_WIFI_SAE_MODE WPA3_SAE_PWE_HUNT_AND_PECK
#define EXAMPLE_H2E_IDENTIFIER ""
#elif CONFIG_ESP_WPA3_SAE_PWE_HASH_TO_ELEMENT
#define ESP_WIFI_SAE_MODE WPA3_SAE_PWE_HASH_TO_ELEMENT
#define EXAMPLE_H2E_IDENTIFIER CONFIG_ESP_WIFI_PW_ID
#elif CONFIG_ESP_WPA3_SAE_PWE_BOTH
#define ESP_WIFI_SAE_MODE WPA3_SAE_PWE_BOTH
#define EXAMPLE_H2E_IDENTIFIER CONFIG_ESP_WIFI_PW_ID
#endif
#if CONFIG_ESP_WIFI_AUTH_OPEN
#define ESP_WIFI_SCAN_AUTH_MODE_THRESHOLD WIFI_AUTH_OPEN
#elif CONFIG_ESP_WIFI_AUTH_WEP
#define ESP_WIFI_SCAN_AUTH_MODE_THRESHOLD WIFI_AUTH_WEP
#elif CONFIG_ESP_WIFI_AUTH_WPA_PSK
#define ESP_WIFI_SCAN_AUTH_MODE_THRESHOLD WIFI_AUTH_WPA_PSK
#elif CONFIG_ESP_WIFI_AUTH_WPA2_PSK
#define ESP_WIFI_SCAN_AUTH_MODE_THRESHOLD WIFI_AUTH_WPA2_PSK
#elif CONFIG_ESP_WIFI_AUTH_WPA_WPA2_PSK
#define ESP_WIFI_SCAN_AUTH_MODE_THRESHOLD WIFI_AUTH_WPA_WPA2_PSK
#elif CONFIG_ESP_WIFI_AUTH_WPA3_PSK
#define ESP_WIFI_SCAN_AUTH_MODE_THRESHOLD WIFI_AUTH_WPA3_PSK
#elif CONFIG_ESP_WIFI_AUTH_WPA3_WPA3_PSK
#define ESP_WIFI_SCAN_AUTH_MODE_THRESHOLD WIFI_AUTH_WPA2_WPA3_PSK
#elif CONFIG_ESP_WIFI_AUTH_WAPI_PSK
#define ESP_WIFI_SCAN_AUTH_MODE_THRESHOLD WIFI_AUTH_WAPI_PSK
#endif

/* FreeRTOS event group to signal when we are connected*/
static EventGroupHandle_t s_wifi_event_group;

#define WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT BIT0
#define WIFI_FAIL_BIT      BIT1

static const char *TAG = "wifi station";

static int s_retry_num = 0;

//static const uint8_t BROADCAST_MAC[ESP_NOW_ETH_ALEN] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};
static const uint8_t MASTER_MAC[ESP_NOW_ETH_ALEN] = {0x40, 0x4c, 0xca, 0x4f, 0x09, 0x84};

static const uint8_t Nsensor = 1;
static uint8_t slave_mac[2][ESP_NOW_ETH_ALEN] = {
    {0x40, 0x4c, 0xca, 0x50, 0x5a, 0xbc},
    {0x40, 0x4c, 0xca, 0x4f, 0x09, 0xb1}
};


char *Iam;





static void event_handler(void* arg, esp_event_base_t event_base, int32_t event_id, void* event_data);
void wifi_init_sta(void);

void espnow_send_cb(const uint8_t *mac_addr, esp_now_send_status_t status);
void espnow_recv_cb(const uint8_t *mac_addr, const uint8_t *data, int len);
void espnow_init(void);
static void drt_peer_add(uint8_t *peer_addr);


void app_main(void)
{
   //Initialize NVS
    esp_err_t ret = nvs_flash_init();
    if (ret == ESP_ERR_NVS_NO_FREE_PAGES || ret == ESP_ERR_NVS_NEW_VERSION_FOUND) {
      ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_erase());
      ret = nvs_flash_init();
    }
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(ret);


   uint8_t mac[6];

   ret= esp_read_mac(mac, ESP_MAC_WIFI_STA);

   if ( ret==ESP_OK ) {
      printf("ESP32 MAC Address        = "MACSTR"\n", MAC2STR(mac));
      printf("ESP32 MASTER MAC Address = "MACSTR"\n", MAC2STR(MASTER_MAC));


      if ( memcmp(mac, MASTER_MAC, ESP_NOW_ETH_ALEN)==0 ){
         Iam = malloc(7);
         strcpy(Iam, "Master");
         printf("I am Master\n");
      } else {
        Iam = malloc(6);
         for(int i=0;i<Nsensor;i++)
         {
            if ( memcmp(mac, slave_mac[i], ESP_NOW_ETH_ALEN)==0 ) {
               strcpy(Iam, "Slave");
               printf("I am Slave %d\n", i+1);
               break;
            }
         }
      }
   } else {
      printf("Fail to get ESP32 MAC Address\n");
      return ;
   }

   //vTaskDelay(5000/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "ESP_WIFI_MODE_STA");
    if ( strcmp(Iam, "Master" )==0 ) {
       wifi_init_sta(); // <---wifi station mode

        //If you comment one line above and uncomment the eight lines below, espnow communication works properly.
       //ESP_LOGI(TAG, "ESP_WIFI_MODE_STA");
       //ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_init());
       //ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_create_default());
       //esp_netif_create_default_wifi_sta();
       //wifi_init_config_t cfg = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
       //ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_init(&cfg));
       //ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_STA));
       //ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_start());

       espnow_init();

       for(int i=0;i<Nsensor;i++) {
          drt_peer_add(slave_mac[i]);
       }
    } else {
       ESP_LOGI(TAG, "ESP_WIFI_MODE_STA");
       ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_init());
       ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_create_default());

       esp_netif_create_default_wifi_sta();

       wifi_init_config_t cfg = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
       ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_init(&cfg));
       ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_STA));
       ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_start());

       espnow_init();
       drt_peer_add(MASTER_MAC);
    }


   printf("...................................................I am %s\n", Iam);

    char data[] = "Hello, Slave";
    if ( strcmp(Iam, "Master")==0 ) {
        printf("I am MASTER .........................\n");
        while(1)
        {
            esp_now_send(slave_mac[0], (uint8_t *)data, strlen(data));
            vTaskDelay(1000/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        }
    }



}

static void drt_peer_add(uint8_t *peer_addr)
{
   esp_now_peer_info_t *peer = malloc(sizeof(esp_now_peer_info_t));
   if (peer==NULL) {
       ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Malloc peer information fail");
       // vSemaphoreDelete(drt_queue);
       esp_now_deinit();
       return;
   }

   memset(peer, 0, sizeof(esp_now_peer_info_t));
   peer->channel = 0;
   peer->ifidx = ESP_IF_WIFI_STA;
   peer->encrypt = false;
   memcpy(peer->peer_addr, peer_addr, ESP_NOW_ETH_ALEN);
   ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_now_add_peer(peer));
   free(peer);
}





static void event_handler(void* arg, esp_event_base_t event_base, int32_t event_id, void* event_data)
{
    if (event_base == WIFI_EVENT && event_id == WIFI_EVENT_STA_START) {
        esp_wifi_connect();
    } else if (event_base == WIFI_EVENT && event_id == WIFI_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED) {
        if (s_retry_num < EXAMPLE_ESP_MAXIMUM_RETRY) {
            esp_wifi_connect();
            s_retry_num++;
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "retry to connect to the AP");
        } else {
            xEventGroupSetBits(s_wifi_event_group, WIFI_FAIL_BIT);
        }
        ESP_LOGI(TAG,"connect to the AP fail");
    } else if (event_base == IP_EVENT && event_id == IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP) {
        ip_event_got_ip_t* event = (ip_event_got_ip_t*) event_data;
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "got ip:" IPSTR, IP2STR(&event->ip_info.ip));
        s_retry_num = 0;
        xEventGroupSetBits(s_wifi_event_group, WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT);
    }
}

void wifi_init_sta(void)
{
    s_wifi_event_group = xEventGroupCreate();

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_init());

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_create_default());
    esp_netif_create_default_wifi_sta();

    wifi_init_config_t cfg = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_init(&cfg));

    esp_event_handler_instance_t instance_any_id;
    esp_event_handler_instance_t instance_got_ip;
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_instance_register(WIFI_EVENT,
                                                        ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID,
                                                        &event_handler,
                                                        NULL,
                                                        &instance_any_id));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_instance_register(IP_EVENT,
                                                        IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP,
                                                        &event_handler,
                                                        NULL,
                                                        &instance_got_ip));

    wifi_config_t wifi_config = {
        .sta = {
            .ssid = EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID,
            .password = EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS,
            /* Authmode threshold resets to WPA2 as default if password matches WPA2 standards (pasword len => 8).
             * If you want to connect the device to deprecated WEP/WPA networks, Please set the threshold value
             * to WIFI_AUTH_WEP/WIFI_AUTH_WPA_PSK and set the password with length and format matching to
             * WIFI_AUTH_WEP/WIFI_AUTH_WPA_PSK standards.
             */
            .threshold.authmode = ESP_WIFI_SCAN_AUTH_MODE_THRESHOLD,
            .sae_pwe_h2e = ESP_WIFI_SAE_MODE,
            .sae_h2e_identifier = EXAMPLE_H2E_IDENTIFIER,
        },
    };
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_STA) );
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_config(WIFI_IF_STA, &wifi_config) );
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_start() );

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "wifi_init_sta finished.");

    /* Waiting until either the connection is established (WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT) or connection failed for the maximum
     * number of re-tries (WIFI_FAIL_BIT). The bits are set by event_handler() (see above) */
    EventBits_t bits = xEventGroupWaitBits(s_wifi_event_group,
            WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT | WIFI_FAIL_BIT,
            pdFALSE,
            pdFALSE,
            portMAX_DELAY);

    /* xEventGroupWaitBits() returns the bits before the call returned, hence we can test which event actually
     * happened. */
    if (bits & WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT) {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "connected to ap SSID:%s password:%s",
                 EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID, EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS);
    } else if (bits & WIFI_FAIL_BIT) {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Failed to connect to SSID:%s, password:%s",
                 EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID, EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS);
    } else {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "UNEXPECTED EVENT");
    }
}




void espnow_send_cb(const uint8_t *mac_addr, esp_now_send_status_t status) {
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Send Status: %s", status == ESP_NOW_SEND_SUCCESS ? "Success" : "Fail");
}

// ESP-NOW
void espnow_recv_cb(const uint8_t *mac_addr, const uint8_t *data, int len) {
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Received data from: " MACSTR ", len: %d", MAC2STR(mac_addr), len);
}

void espnow_init(void) {
    // ESP-NOW 
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_now_init());
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_now_register_send_cb(espnow_send_cb));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_now_register_recv_cb(espnow_recv_cb));

}


I don't know if I've found a solution, but currently both espnow and wifi are communicating.
Sending data to another device using espnow from the device I was trying to connect to wifi (master) failed, so I tried the opposite. In other words, data was sent from a device (slave) not connected to WiFi to the master via espnow, and this was successful. After that, espnow communication from master to slave was also successful.
In summary, when communication to send data from a master using wifi+espnow to a slave (espnow only) fails, I would recommend trying to send data from the slave to the master in the opposite direction.
